# How can I set node and link text manually in separated input?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have simple python flask app where I send `JSON` data to my `HTML` and with `goJS` I display my graph which looks like this:

[image]

I want to change my selected node text inside input and when I click on `"update node text"` button I want to update node text with text from my `input`. I managed to get node text with help of this diagram listener:

```
myDiagram.addDiagramListener("ObjectSingleClicked", function(e) {
  console.log("clicked!");
  var part = e.subject.part;
  //part.data is the node object
  if (!(part instanceof go.Link)) {
    console.log("its not link!");
    console.log(part.data);
    document.getElementById("nodeText").value = part.data.text;

  } else {
    console.log("its link!");
  }
});
```

I am stuck with updating node text and don't know how to do it. Also I want to make same thing with link text. I searched and googled but no solutions nor examples for this case. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I should say that the most common way to allow users to edit text in diagrams is to set [**TextBlock.editable**](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/textblocks.html#Editing) to true and to add a [TwoWay **Binding**](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/dataBinding.html#ReasonsForTwoWayBindings) of **TextBlock.text** to some data property.  This allows users to edit the text in-place rather than in separate HTML fields.

But it is common to have editing of properties in HTML fields.  Assuming there is at least a one way Binding from some data property to the **TextBlock.text** property in your node, your textarea's blur (or change?) event handler just needs to call [**Model.setDataProperty**](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html#setDataProperty) within a transaction.  Read more about [modifying models](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/usingModels.html#ModifyingModels) and [transactions](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/transactions.html#SupportUndoManager).

Finally if you have a bunch of properties that you want to allow the user to edit, and especially if the number of properties might vary, you might want to use the GoJS [DataInspector](https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/DataInspector.js).  It is demonstrated by the [Org Chart Editor sample](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html) and the [Data Inspector sample](https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/dataInspector.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!